# Does Bing maps silverlight API work on Windows phone 7?

Tags: bing-maps, windows-phone

Has anyone seen any good resources on using Bing Maps Silverlight APIs on WP7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few links.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Learn/Courses/WP7TrainingKit/WP7Silverlight/UsingBingMapsLab/Overview

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955762.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681883.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the recently released [ArcGIS API for Windows Phone](http://links.esri.com/windowsphone) - currently in beta.  In addition to Bing Maps support, the API has very robust capabilities for adding ArcGIS, OGC, OpenStreetMap, and client-side features (i.e. graphics) to the map.

Answer (score 1):

Yes bing maps 7 silverlight for phone supports win 7 mobile. There is also support for Android and iOS.

Full details of mobile support here:
http://www.georelated.com/2012/02/cloud-web-map-api-services-reviewed_19.html

Other options include google maps:
Google Maps supports many mobile platforms and their html/js control is also also supported on many mobile devices.
http://www.georelated.com/2012/02/cloud-web-map-api-services-reviewed.html